# NodeJS Mongoose throwing an error: "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose to connect to mongodb with ssl options enabled

I have written the following code:

```
var certFileBuf = fs.readFileSync(config.db[name].sslCertPath);
conn[name] = mongoose.createConnection(config.db[name].conn, {
    user: config.db[name].user,
    pwd: config.db[name].pwd,
    server: {
      sslCA: certFileBuf, ssl: true, sslInvalidHostNameAllowed: true, sslValidate: false,
     sslPEMKeyPwd: config.db[name].sslCertPassword
              }
});
conn[name].user = config.db[name].user;
conn[name].pass = config.db[name].pwd;
```

I am getting following error:

```
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'self signed certificate in certificate chain'
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect mongoose with remote db with ssl using: **sslValidate: true**

This is used in the case of self-generated certificate.

A simpler way of connecting using mongoose(with ssl):

```
// create mongo ssl config
const mongoSSL = {
      sslKey: require('fs').readFileSync('../../key.pem'),
      sslCert: require('fs').readFileSync('../../cert.pem'),
      sslValidate: true, // in case of self-generated certificate
};

// connect with remote db with ssl 
mongoose.connect(
        mongodb:// + MONGODB_USERNAME + ':' + MONGODB_PASSWORD + @2.18.4.13:27017/, 
        {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true},  
        mongoSSL
);
```

Comment: I am not using `moongoose.connect` instead i am using `mongoose.createConnection` can you update your answer using `mongoose.createConnection`?

Comment: The mongoose.createConnection() function takes the same arguments as mongoose.connect() and returns a new connection.
mongoose.createConnection('url',options);